# Best way to route USB devices when using VMWare Workstation and VMWare-KVM

Tags: usb, vmware-workstation, vmware-player

I am using VMWare Workstation, but in order to hide the host from my users all VMs I want to deploay will run in VMware-KVM.
When connecting a USB device to the host, the different classes of devices should be handled differently: USB storage devices should be connected directly to the host, but other USB devices like USB serial adapters should always be connected to the guest.

The first thing I noticed is that there is a difference between the WMare Workstation UI and the vmware-kvm.exe how it handles USB redirection: even if you set the Poprey "USB: Connect the device to host" in Workstation settings, VMware-kvm.exe will ignore that and connect the device to whichever has the focus, i.e. if the guest is in fullscreen, it will connect it to the guest, if the host is in fullscreen then it will connect to the host.

What I want is a rule-based behaviour such as described in the VMWare KB, unfortunately I do not get it to work right.

First of all, I tried to add the following lines to my VMX file:

```
usb.generic.autoconnect = "FALSE"
usb.autoConnect.device0 = "0x403:0x1031"
usb.autoConnect.device1 = "0x403:0x1032"
```

Which should mean: connect all devices to the host by default (autoconnect = false), but devices with the PID and VID (they belong to a USB serial adapter I use) given in the following two lines should be connected to the guest.

This seems to work if the devices are connected during startup of the virtual machine (USB Stick stays with host, Serial adapters are connected to guest), but as soon as I remove the USB serial adapter and connect it to another USB port (while the machine is still running), it gets connected to the host instead of the guest.

So how can I force my USB devices to automatically connect to host or guest based on rules that I give using PID and VID? It looks simple in theory, but doesn' really work for me yet in real life.

Thank you for any hints!

Comment: The USB device behavior you want should be handled by the VMware USB Arbitration Service.  If the USB device settings you configure in Workstation aren't being honored by vmware-kvm, it sounds like I neglected some step to make vmware-kvm use that service.  Argh.  Unfortunately, none of that helps you, and I'm no longer at VMware to fix it myself.  You could report a bug.  Sorry. =(

Answer (score 1):

Look in the logs of the vm, find the name of your device. Copy from `name:`  to when the `pid:xxx` ends.  Put in your `.vmx` file as example below.

```
usb.autoConnect.device0 = "name:Cambridge\\ Silicon\\ Radio\\ Bluetooth\\ Adapter vid:0a12 pid:0001"
```